# How do I share methods between 2 differents Swing windows?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

I have a Swing application in which I have multiple windows with different goals but they all have 2 things in common:

- They use a specific object which is business logic related
- They have to update some widgets with the specific object's stuff

So, in order to avoid redundancy of code, I wanted to share some of those routines.
Maybe an example can be more clear:

```
public class WindowA {
     private JLabel labelA;
     // ...
     private void updateLabelInACertainManner() {
          labelA.setText(this.specificObject.getText());
     }
}

public class WindowB {
     private JLabel labelB;
     // ...
     private void updateLabelInACertainManner() {
          labelA.setText(this.specificObject.getText());
     }
}
```

How can I share `updateLabelInACertainManner()`, knowing that `specificObject` references the same object in both classes ?

I was thinking about inheriting both `WindowA` and `WindowB` from a `WindowRoot` which contains the method but how to do so having `labelA` and `labelB` are not the same object, not necessarily created in same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the label whose text should be changed as a parameter to the method in the superclass:

```
public class SuperWindow {
    protected void updateLabel(JLabel label) {
       label.setText("foo");
    }
}

public class WindowA extends SuperWindow {
    private JLabel labelA;
    //...

    private void somethingHappened() {
      updateLabel(labelA);
    }
}
```

Or you could write a getter for the label in the specific subclasses:

```
public class SuperWindow {
   protected abstract JLabel getLabel();

   protected void updateLabel() {
     getLabel().setText("foo");
   }
}

public class WindowA extends SuperWindow {
   private JLabel labelA;
   //...

   @Override
   protected JLabel getLabel() {
      return labelA;
   }

   private void somethingHappened() {
      updateLabel();
   }
}
```

And the same for `specificObject`.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I was needed to get me in the right way :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read about this [approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) or about this [approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter).